# How can I get the name of the input file in a Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, argv

#### File *monday.csv*

```
223.22;1256.4
227.08;1244.8
228.08;1244.7
229.13;1255.0
227.89;1243.2
224.77;1277.8
```

#### File *tuesday.csv*

```
227.02;1266.3
227.09;1234.9
225.18;1244.7
224.13;1255.3
228.59;1263.2
224.70;1247.6
```

This Perl one-liner gives me the row with the highest value in the second column from the rows where in the first column the first three digits are 227 or 226 from the file "monday.csv":

```
perl -F\; -ane '$hash{$_} = $F[1] if /22[78]/; END{ print and exit for sort{ $hash{$b} &lt;=> $hash{$a} } keys %hash }' monday.csv
```

This Perl one-liner gives me the row with the highest value in the second column from the rows where in the first column the first 3 digits are 227 or 226 from all *day.csv files:

```
perl -F\; -ane '$hash{$_} = $F[1] if /22[78]/; END{ print and exit for sort{ $hash{$b} &lt;=> $hash{$a} } keys %hash }' *day.csv
```

How could I rewrite this one-liner to get an output like

> filename : "row with the highest value in the second column from the rows where in the first column the first 3 digits are 227 or 226 from the file 'filename.csv'"

for each `*day.csv` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$ARGV` for the current file name. If you're only interested in the max, no need to store all the values and then sort them; instead, just store the max for each file. Also, your regex probably should be anchored to the start of the line.

```
# Line breaks added for display purposes.
perl -F\; -ane '
    $max{$ARGV} = $F[1] if /^22[78]/ and $F[1] > $max{$ARGV};
    END{ print "$_\t$max{$_}" for sort keys %max}
' *day.csv
```

Or, if you want to store the entire line where the max occurs:

```
perl -F\; -ane '
    ($max{$ARGV}{ln}, $max{$ARGV}{mx}) = ($_, $F[1])
        if /^22[78]/ and $F[1] > $max{$ARGV}{mx};
    END{ print "$_\t$max{$_}{ln}" for sort keys %max}
' *day.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

The filename is contained in the [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) variable:

> **$ARGV**
>
> contains the name of the current file when reading from <>.

---

However, the one-liners presented have an issue; what if you have repeated values of your first column?

A better one-liner would be:

```
$ perl -F/;/ -MList::Util=max -lane 'push @{ $wanted{$ARGV} }, $F[1] if $F[0] =~ /22[78]/; } END { print "$ARGV : ", max(@{ $wanted{$_} }) for keys %wanted;' *.csv
```

---

Based on the comment:

```
$ perl -F/;/ -lane '$wanted{$ARGV} = \@F if $F[1] >= $wanted->{$ARGV}[1] && $F[0] =~ /22[78]/; } END { print "$_ : @$wanted{$_}" for keys %wanted;' *.csv
```

Comment: I don't see the problem with repeated values.

Comment: in the first column. But I see a problem with repeated values in the second column. The reason is, it forgot to mention, that I would like to have the last value in the file from the highest values if there is more then one highest value per file.

Comment: But I think there are a lot of errors in your second one-liner.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you can use $ARGV.